# How do I save the CLion console output to a file?

Tags: console-application, clion, logfile

I'm running an executable I built, within CLion. The bottom of the window has a pane with the executable's console output. I see a button from printing it and for clearing it - but not for saving it to a file. Can I do that, other than by manually copying the text into an editor (or a cat > `logfile.txt`)?

Note: I'm using CLion 2022.3.